# fatal error on loading my trained keras model in r

Tags: r, keras, shiny

I have h5 model already trained. I want to load that model to my r application.

Code used is :

`library(keras)
 m <- keras::load_model_hdf5("www/ae_model.h5")`

Even tried:

`m <- load_model_hdf5("www/ae_model.h5")`

My R session asks for restart.

it shows `R session Aborted R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated` on my screen.

Comment: What IDE are you using.... RStudio?

Comment: @Sotos Yes.. R studio and even updated my R also

Comment: Try loading it directly to the console

Comment: @Sotos I have tried loading it on my R studio console also. It had worked for me previously.

Comment: Maybe trywith different versions of TensorFlow.

Comment: Hello,
I didn't know Keras package, but as I look the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keras/keras.pdf), I did not find the `load_model_hdf5()` function. Are you sure it is not the `mobilenet_load_model_hdf5()` function you're looking for? 
Also, it may happen that this function you are trying to use does not return a Value matching a variable. You might just try:
```r
load_model_hdf5("www/ae_model.h5")
```
I hoped this helped.

Comment: I have similar problem after changing Python environment and using Keras with Reticulate library in R. The way I "solved" it is opening R in the terminal (not Rstudio), it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by myself, I made sure that the file is stored in my current working directory. and added another "/" to the URL i.e

```
m <- load_model_hdf5("www//ae_model.h5").
```

To my existing code. Thank you for the response.